# recursively return json output each iteration python

Tags: python, json, csv, recursion, avro

I am new to python, I was trying to create avro reading the json, before that I was trying to generate json using csv by `csv.DictReader()` in python and here I wanted to return a function which generate json return recursively that can be used in avro generation function , But whenever I try to do the return I get only one entry,

Can we achive this through recursion or any other way?

```
def get_test():

     with open("test.csv",'r') as f:
       reader=csv.DictReader(f)
       for row in reader:
           json = {
                   "field1": row['field1'],
                   "field2": bool(row['field2']),
                    }
          return json

def avro_gen():

    schema = avro.schema.parse(open("test.avsc", "rb").read())
    with open("test_" + ".avro", 'wb') as f:
        writer = DataFileWriter(f, DatumWriter(), schema)
        for i in range(get_count_csv_row()):
            writer.append(get_Test())
        writer.close()
```

`get_count_csv_row()` count of csv raw

Expected output:

```
{"field1": "test1","field2": true }
{"field1": "test2","field2": false}
```

Actual:

```
{"field1": "test1","field2": true }
{"field1": "test1","field2": true }
```

each iteration I expect different json, but I am getting the same output to `avro_gen()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `get_test()` function you are returning the first json. You need to collect all of them and return the collection in the end:

```py
def get_test():
    json_list = []
    with open("test.csv",'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            json = {
                "field1": row['field1'],
                "field2": bool(row['field2'])
            }
            json_list.append(json)
    return json_list
```

Personally, I would use comprehension to keep it light:

```py
def get_test():
    with open("test.csv",'r') as f:
        return [
            {
                "field1": row['field1'],
                "field2": bool(row['field2'])
            }
            for row in csv.DictReader(f)
        ]
```

Ideally, I would actually use `pandas`:

```py
def get_test():
    df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
    return df[['field1', 'field2']].apply({'field2': bool}, axis=1)
```

Then, in your function, you need to process all of these json objects, writing them one by one to your avro:

```py
def avro_gen():
    schema = avro.schema.parse(open("test.avsc", "rb").read())
    with open("test_" + ".avro", 'wb') as f:
        writer = DataFileWriter(f, DatumWriter(), schema)
        for json in get_test():
            writer.append(json)
        writer.close()
```